# Perform cumulative sum on a column of pandas dataframe ignoring NAN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I want to perform cumulative sum on the column 'NEW1' based on each ORDER. The below code works partially but it doesnot ignore Nan's meanig I am expecting the value of 'cumsum' to be 8 for the last row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':["A", "A", "B", "B"], 'NEW1':[np.nan, 5, 8, np.nan]})
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['ORDER'])['NEW1'].cumsum()
df

    ORDER   NEW1    cumsum
0   A       NaN     NaN
1   A       5.0     5.0
2   B       8.0     8.0
3   B       NaN     NaN
```

My expected output:

```
    ORDER   NEW1    cumsum
0   A       NaN     NaN
1   A       5.0     5.0
2   B       8.0     8.0
3   B       NaN     8.0
```

Comment: What if you set `skipna=True`?

Answer (score 3):

`fillna()` before `groupby`, and use `transform`

```
df['cumsum']=df.fillna(0).groupby('ORDER')['NEW1'].transform('cumsum')



ORDER  NEW1  cumsum
0     A   NaN     0.0
1     A   5.0     5.0
2     B   8.0     8.0
3     B   NaN     8.0
```

Comment: This isn't ideal because it fills cumsum with zero on the first row when it "should" be NaN as well

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use apply with lambda:

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['ORDER'])['NEW1'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0).cumsum())
```

Comment: Sorry @Scott Boston, wrong edit. My sincere apologies

Answer (score 1):

Let's use an `expanding` `sum`, which will treat `NaN` as you like:

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('ORDER')['NEW1'].expanding().sum().reset_index(0, drop=True)

  ORDER  NEW1  cumsum
0     A   NaN     NaN
1     A   5.0     5.0
2     B   8.0     8.0
3     B   NaN     8.0
```